# Animation for drawRect drawings

Tags: ios, animation, calayer, drawrect

A part of my app is a statistics-function. I draw in a `UIView` a path and fill it with a color... now I want to make an animation that the path draws through the `UIView` from the left side to the right side.

I read about CALayer, but I'm not sure how that works... some sample code or links would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a great post:
http://tumbljack.com/post/179975074/complex-interpolation-with-cashapelayer-free

In general this is a duplicate of this:
[Animating a shape with CoreAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767401/animating-a-shape-with-coreanimation)

Cheers

Oded